# Is it possible to run Identity Server 4 as an API/Service, separate from Login/Registration/ForgottenPassword?

Tags: asp.net-core, identityserver4

For example, I'd like to run Identity Server as an API which other resources authorise against. I'd also like to have a separate Web Application to handle Login/Registration/ForgottenPassword pages which uses said Identity Server API. I'm used to running both within the same application.

I appreciate this is a very light description for the question. I'm fairly certain I read somewhere that IdentityServer4 can be run as just a service/API.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can. You have to use the `endpoints`. Have a look at [all](http://docs.identityserver.io/en/release/endpoints/discovery.html) of them. I think that the one that suits best your requirements is the `Token endpoint`. There, by specifying some params (including username and password), you can practically login and receive the tokens.

Btw - Identity Server doesn't support OOTB any forgotten password or registration support. This should be custom. And also I guess that you are not using `InMemory` users, so basically it is up to you how to design this, but yes - it will be separate from Identity Server.

Comment: Thanks. I'm using https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4.Quickstart.UI for the Web Application. I'm guessing these are written for an IdentityServer running in the same application, using AspNetIdentity.

Comment: Yes, this QuickStart is for a basic Identity Server UI (web application) that is coupled with the services. If you need something to solve your case, you can use them as a demo, but you have to modify and separate the things.

Comment: It's worth noting that using the resource owner password flow via the token endpoint is NOT recommended. This article pretty much sums it up: https://www.scottbrady91.com/OAuth/Why-the-Resource-Owner-Password-Credentials-Grant-Type-is-not-Authentication-nor-Suitable-for-Modern-Applications

My recommendation would be to make the IDS4 service a standalone separate service with its own sign in an account management UI and use hybrid or implicit flow when signing in from other applications.

Comment: @mackie I know this is old but relevant to my needs. If IDS4 is separated so what is your recommendation for registering new users? Should it be on that service, I mean forms with logic or should I expose that logic through custom API on that service and call it from my client (where UI resides)? Thanks in advice for any help